# How do you disable the bell sound in Bash on Windows?

Tags: bash, visual-studio, windows-10

I'm currently using Bash on Windows 10 in my Visual Studio Code. The bell ring is extremely annoying and I would like a good solution to disable it (other that turning the volume off or not making any mistakes...).

Comment: You might want to check the settings for VSC. There is probably something that you can change to set what a "bell" means: make an actual sound,  flash the screen, display an icon, etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Run this in your windows bash shell:

```
echo "set bell-style none" >> ~/.inputrc
```

or edit `.inputrc` manually, then add `set bell-style none`, and restart your open bash shell to take effect.

Comment: Don't make the mistake of trying to use `set bell-style visual` as you might on linux... that doesn't slay the bell!